# "expected backend CPU and dtype Double but got backend CPU and dtype Float" on a server

Tags: python, bash, pytorch, anaconda, conda

**What I am doing:**

I am trying to run the following code from github with different datasets. https://github.com/k-han/AutoNovel I edited rotationloader and added some data loaders, and the rest is same as github.

**The problem:**

The code worked fine with smaller server, but I am encountering some error when I am running this on bigger(stronger) server. The error message is `RuntimeError: expected backend CPU and dtype Double but got backend CPU and dtype Float` The full error trace is at the end of the question.

**What I tried:**
I was suggested to make a script and put it where my code is. This script was to

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=test
#SBATCH --output=test.out
#SBATCH --account=guest
#SBATCH --partition=guest-gpu
#SBATCH --qos=low-gpu
#SBATCH --time=02:00:00
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:TitanX:1   # Request 1 TitanX GPU
 
# Load modules required for your job
module load cuda/9.0
module load share_modules/HOOMD/2.3.5_sp
 
# Path to your executable
./mygpucode.exe
```

Writing and adding this script to the file did not make any changes.

Also I was suggested to add `x.cuda().double()` when x is name of a tensor, but I am not sure where to add this.

Please let me know if I missed any information. Thank you in advance!

**Full Error Trace:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "selfsupervised_learning.py", line 178, in <module>
    main()
  File "selfsupervised_learning.py", line 169, in main
    loss_record = train(epoch, model, device, dloader_train, optimizer, exp_lr_scheduler, criterion, args)
  File "selfsupervised_learning.py", line 65, in train
    for batch_idx, (data, label) in enumerate(tqdm(dataloader(epoch))):
  File "/home/mchoi/.conda/envs/auto_novel/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tqdm/_tqdm.py", line 1005, in __iter__
    for obj in iterable:
  File "/home/mchoi/.conda/envs/auto_novel/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 582, in __next__
    return self._process_next_batch(batch)
  File "/home/mchoi/.conda/envs/auto_novel/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 608, in _process_next_batch
    raise batch.exc_type(batch.exc_msg)
RuntimeError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mchoi/.conda/envs/auto_novel/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/worker.py", line 99, in _worker_loop
    samples = collate_fn([dataset[i] for i in batch_indices])
  File "/home/mchoi/.conda/envs/auto_novel/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/worker.py", line 99, in <listcomp>
    samples = collate_fn([dataset[i] for i in batch_indices])
  File "/home/mchoi/.conda/envs/auto_novel/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchnet/dataset/listdataset.py", line 54, in __getitem__
    return self.load(self.list[idx])
  File "/home/mchoi/AutoNovel/data/rotationloader.py", line 219, in _load_function
    self.transform(img0),
  File "/home/mchoi/.conda/envs/auto_novel/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/transforms.py", line 61, in __call__
    img = t(img)
  File "/home/mchoi/.conda/envs/auto_novel/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/transforms.py", line 164, in __call__
    return F.normalize(tensor, self.mean, self.std, self.inplace)
  File "/home/mchoi/.conda/envs/auto_novel/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/functional.py", line 208, in normalize
    tensor.sub_(mean[:, None, None]).div_(std[:, None, None])
RuntimeError: expected backend CPU and dtype Double but got backend CPU and dtype Float
```

Comment: Any chance the compute node is not 64-bit?

Comment: @merv The node is running in 64-bit.